Should I use parameter standard deviations or standard errors when bootstrapping to generate confidence intervals about logistic regression models?
I have binary response data that I've modeled using simple logistic regression. I have data from a few species and from several individuals of each species. I've modeled each individual separately, so I have separate slopes and intercepts for each individual.
I calculate the average slope and the average intercept for each species and I use those as my parameter estimates for each species.
I want to generate 95 % confidence intervals about these models by bootstrapping. Since I have multiple slopes and multiple intercepts for each species (one from each individual), I could calculate standard deviations or standard errors of these parameters. Should I use the standard deviation or the standard error of these parameters when I bootstrap?
I don't really have enough individuals from each species to resample the actual values (which would be a classic bootstrap, I think). Instead, I'm assuming these parameters come from a normal distribution, and then I'm randomly generating values from that distribution.
Thanks!

Confidence intervals of what?

That's probably the key, right? If it's confidence intervals about the mean responses for each species, we'd use standard errors, and if it's confidence intervals about the possible raw data points, we'd use standard deviations, right?

What do you want to calculate a confidence interval for? It might be that bootstrap is entirely unnecessary or that your overall approach is not the right one for what you want to learn from your data. (For instance, it seems like a random effect (for the individuals) might be reasonable to include in your model.)

We would like to show shaded regions around mean response curves in a figure to give readers a sense of the uncertainty of these models.

Perhaps it would be worth asking how to do that, maybe discussing the details about how many individuals you have and the possibility of a random effect.

That sounds good - thanks
